# C# Convert Relative to Absolute Links in HTML String

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing, url

I'm mirroring some internal websites for backup purposes.  As of right now I basically use this c# code:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] dl = client.DownloadData(url);
```

This just basically downloads the html and into a byte array.  This is what I want.  The problem however is that the links within the html are most of the time relative, not absolute.

I basically want to append whatever the full http://domain.is before the relative link as to convert it to an absolute link that will redirect to the original content.  I'm basically just concerned with href= and src=.  Is there a regex expression that will cover some of the basic cases?

Edit [My Attempt]:

```
public static string RelativeToAbsoluteURLS(string text, string absoluteUrl)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return text;
    }

    String value = Regex.Replace(
        text, 
        "<(.*?)(src|href)=\"(?!http)(.*?)\"(.*?)>", 
        "<$1$2=\"" + absoluteUrl + "$3\"$4>", 
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    return value.Replace(absoluteUrl + "/", absoluteUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most robust solution would be to use the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) as others have suggested. However a reasonable solution using regular expressions is possible using the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) overload that takes a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) delegate, as follows:

```
var baseUri = new Uri("http://test.com");
var pattern = @"(?<name>src|href)=""(?<value>/[^""]*)""";
var matchEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(
    match =>
    {
        var value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
        Uri uri;

        if (Uri.TryCreate(baseUri, value, out uri))
        {
            var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
            return string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", name, uri.AbsoluteUri);
        }

        return null;
    });
var adjustedHtml = Regex.Replace(originalHtml, pattern, matchEvaluator);
```

The above sample searches for attributes named src and href that contain double quoted values starting with a forward slash. For each match, the static [Uri.TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131573.aspx) method is used to determine if the value is a valid relative uri.

Note that this solution doesn't handle single quoted attribute values and certainly doesn't work on poorly formed HTML with unquoted values.

Comment: I added an edit that works at least in my few test cases.  Looking at the regex stuff, it looks fairly similar, but your code looks much more complicated.  I honestly have never used the MatchEvaluator and the delegate stuff; is your code better?

Comment: Using a MatchEvaluator allows you to vastly simplify the regex pattern and use the much more robust Uri.TryCreate method instead. A regex that matches all possible URIs would be extremely complex.

Answer (score 5):

You should use HtmlAgility pack to load the HTML, access all the hrefs using it, and then use the Uri class to convert from relative to absolute as necessary.

See for example http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/a-simple-web-crawler-in-c-using-htmlagilitypack/

Comment: i did try your example, but there seems to be a bug. if i have a baseUrl as `http://ww.baseurl.com/somedir` and i try to create an absolut path adding `/login.php` using your method, i get `http://ww.baseurl.com/login.php` instead of `http://ww.baseurl.com/somedir/login.php`

Answer (score 5):

```
Uri WebsiteImAt = new Uri(
       "http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp?q=1&s=2,2#a");
string href = new Uri(WebsiteImAt, "/something/somethingelse/filename.asp")
       .AbsoluteUri;
string href2 = new Uri(WebsiteImAt, "something.asp").AbsoluteUri;
string href3 = new Uri(WebsiteImAt, "something").AbsoluteUri;
```

which *with your `Regex`-based approach* is *probably* (untested) mappable to:

```
        String value = Regex.Replace(text, "<(.*?)(src|href)=\"(?!http)(.*?)\"(.*?)>", match => 
            "<" + match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value + "=\""
                + new Uri(WebsiteImAt, match.Groups[3].Value).AbsoluteUri + "\""
                + match.Groups[4].Value + ">",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

I should also advise **not** to use `Regex` here, but to apply the Uri trick to some code using a DOM, perhaps `XmlDocument` (if xhtml) or the HTML Agility Pack (otherwise), looking at all `//@src` or `//@href` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be the most robust of solutions it should get the job done.

```
var host = "http://domain.is";
var someHtml = @"
<a href=""/some/relative"">Relative</a>
<img src=""/some/relative"" />
<a href=""http://domain.is/some/absolute"">Absolute</a>
<img src=""http://domain.is/some/absolute"" />
";


someHtml = someHtml.Replace("src=\"" + host,"src=\"");
someHtml = someHtml.Replace("href=\"" + host,"src=\"");
someHtml = someHtml.Replace("src=\"","src=\"" + host);
someHtml = someHtml.Replace("href=\"","src=\"" + host);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) accomplish this. You would do something along these (not tested) lines:

- Load the url
- Select all links
- Load the link into a [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx) and test whether it is relative If it
  relative convert it to absolute
- Update the links value with the new
  uri
- save the file

Here are a few examples:

[Relative to absolute paths in HTML (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719353/relative-to-absolute-paths-in-html-asp-net)

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/a-simple-web-crawler-in-c-using-htmlagilitypack/

Answer (score 0):

I think url is of type string. Use Uri instead with a base uri pointing to your domain:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://domain.is");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, url);

System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] dl = client.DownloadData(myUri);
```

Comment: Does this change the links within the html at myUri from relative to absolute, or is this just better practice for using the WebClient?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function

```
'# converts relative URL ro Absolute URI
    Function RelativeToAbsoluteUrl(ByVal baseURI As Uri, ByVal RelativeUrl As String) As Uri
        ' get action tags, relative or absolute
        Dim uriReturn As Uri = New Uri(RelativeUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        ' Make it absolute if it's relative
        If Not uriReturn.IsAbsoluteUri Then
            Dim baseUrl As Uri = baseURI
            uriReturn = New Uri(baseUrl, uriReturn)
        End If
        Return uriReturn
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple function**

```
public string ConvertRelativeUrlToAbsoluteUrl(string relativeUrl)
{

if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
  return string.Format("https://{0}{1}", Request.Url.Host, Page.ResolveUrl(relativeUrl));
else
  return string.Format("http://{0}{1}", Request.Url.Host, Page.ResolveUrl(relativeUrl));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I figured out how to do it with a fairly simple regex.  It works well for me.  It handles http/https and also root-relative and current directory-relative.

```
var host = "http://www.google.com/";
var baseUrl = host + "images/";
var html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\"/images/srpr/logo3w.png\" /><br /><img src=\"srpr/logo3w.png\" /></body></html>";
var regex = "(?<=(?:href|src)=\")(?!https?://)(?<url>[^\"]+)";
html = Regex.Replace(
    html,
    regex,
    match => match.Groups["url"].Value.StartsWith("/")
        ? host + match.Groups["url"].Value.Substring(1)
        : baseUrl + match.Groups["url"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for, this code snippet can convert all the relative URLs to absolute inside any HTML code:

```
Private Function ConvertALLrelativeLinksToAbsoluteUri(ByVal html As String, ByVal PageURL As String)
    Dim result As String = Nothing
    ' Getting all Href
    Dim opt As New RegexOptions
    Dim XpHref As New Regex("(href="".*?"")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NewSTR As String = html
    For i = 0 To XpHref.Matches(html).Count - 1
        Application.DoEvents()
        Dim Oldurl As String = Nothing
        Dim OldHREF As String = Nothing
        Dim MainURL As New Uri(PageURL)
        OldHREF = XpHref.Matches(html).Item(i).Value
        Oldurl = OldHREF.Replace("href=", "").Replace("HREF=", "").Replace("""", "")
        Dim NEWURL As New Uri(MainURL, Oldurl)
        Dim NewHREF As String = "href=""" & NEWURL.AbsoluteUri & """"
        NewSTR = NewSTR.Replace(OldHREF, NewHREF)
    Next
    html = NewSTR
    Dim XpSRC As New Regex("(src="".*?"")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For i = 0 To XpSRC.Matches(html).Count - 1
        Application.DoEvents()
        Dim Oldurl As String = Nothing
        Dim OldHREF As String = Nothing
        Dim MainURL As New Uri(PageURL)
        OldHREF = XpSRC.Matches(html).Item(i).Value
        Oldurl = OldHREF.Replace("src=", "").Replace("src=", "").Replace("""", "")
        Dim NEWURL As New Uri(MainURL, Oldurl)
        Dim NewHREF As String = "src=""" & NEWURL.AbsoluteUri & """"
        NewSTR = NewSTR.Replace(OldHREF, NewHREF)
    Next
    Return NewSTR
End Function
```