# HTML Agility Pack link correction

Tags: c#, syntax, html-agility-pack

I'm working on a small project and I got a little problem, hope you could help me.

I got this basic few lines that load a given url and takes out some tags:

```
var webGet2 = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = webGet2.Load(pattern);
var htmlMatches = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class=''] | //li[@class='f']");
```

After I'm receiving the collection, I need to run a foreach loop
that can take all the **href** and **src** link and make them valid, because when I'm downloading the source, the link looks like **/folder/folder/image.jpg**
I want to add **http://www.site.com** before each link.

I've build this project with Regex and had no problem doing that, but with HTML agility its not getting straight with my mind.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Convert Relative to Absolute Links in HTML String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836644/c-sharp-convert-relative-to-absolute-links-in-html-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to search some nodes for certain attributes that contain relative urls and change them to absolute urls?  You could do this:

```
static void AdjustAttributes(HtmlNode root, string baseUrl, string attrName)
{
    var query =
        from node in root.Descendants()
        let attr = node.Attributes[attrName]
        where attr != null
        select attr;
    foreach (var attr in query)
    {
        var url = GetAbsoluteUrlString(baseUrl, attr.Value);
        attr.Value = url;
    }
}

static string GetAbsoluteUrlString(string baseUrl, string url)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
        uri = new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), uri);
    return uri.ToString();
}
```

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(pattern);
var selectedNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class=''] | //li[@class='f']");
foreach (var node in selectedNodes)
{
    AdjustAttributes(node, url, "href");
    AdjustAttributes(node, url, "src");
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank alot.
but i need to fix the links after i pull out the **li**s
i need the content, how can i do that?

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted your question.  I thought you were trying to get all those links.  So your goal is to make all relative urls to absolute urls.  Should be simple.

Comment: i was trying to do as it shows here - [link](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) but im having problems with the  **FixLink(att);** it keeps saying its not containing definition. SO i tried replacing it with **this.AbsoluteUrlByRelative(att.Value);** as i saw in other place, and it keep saying the same.. i know im missing something, but im not sure what :\

Comment: Those methods do not exist anywhere in those examples. It's just a place holder for code that you're expected to provide that does the actual changes.