# relative url to new complete url

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, url, relative-url

I have a basu uri and a relative one that am try to create new one from.
i did try the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836644/c-sharp-convert-relative-to-absolute-links-in-html-string), but there seems to be a bug. if i have a baseUrl as

`http://ww.baseurl.com/somedir` and i try to create an absolute path adding

`/login.php` or `login.php` using

`uriReturn = New Uri(baseUri, relativeUri)`, i get

`http://ww.baseurl.com/login.php` instead of

`http://ww.baseurl.com/somedir/login.php`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between `http://ww.baseurl.com/somedir` and `http://ww.baseurl.com/somefile`. Therefore, when you use a relative URI from that address, it will assume the file part of the URI is to be replaced. To indicate that `somedir` is a directory name, and be used as a base URI for the following queries, it should end with a slash: `http://ww.baseurl.com/somedir/`

Comment: thanks, but how do i trickly detect a file and a directory, so i can append the needed slash `/` to the end of a diretory like `http://ww.baseurl.com/somedir/`

Comment: If you're the one configuring the server, you're supposed to know which names are directory names and which are file names. If you're on the client side, there's no way of knowing (except of course to trying to access the URL with trailing '/' first, and if it fails, you know it's a file).

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter in the `Uri` constructor is base URI, which is only the host portion, everything thereafter needs to be in the second parameter (including in your case "somedir").

```
uriReturn = NewUri(baseUri, "somedir/login.php")
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx